# Can't import github project into eclipse - "Next" button greyed out

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I have found the repository I want to import by clicking `File->Import->Repositories from GitHub` finding the [repository I want to clone](https://github.com/openworm/Smoothed-Particle-Hydrodynamics) by using the search but when I select it the `Next` button is greyed out and the `Finish` button closes the dialogue without anything happening.

I feel as though I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

This looks like a bug, when I do `File->Import->Projects from Git->Github` I reach the same dialogue as before but this time `Next` is not greyed out when I find the repository I'm looking for.